# Cannot mount Live USB drive as read/write

Tags: mount, live-usb

Not sure why I cannot mount the Live USB drive as writable.

```
$ sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdd /tmp/usb/
mount: /tmp/usb: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
$ mount|grep sdd
/dev/sdd on /tmp/usb type iso9660 (ro,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)
```

The Live USB with Kubuntu 18.04 has been created using **usb-creator-kde** utility. I would like to use it not only as Live USB but also as storage. I've already tried to format it and then mount as writable. It works.

So what's the problem? Obviously not the device. But at the same time I remember to have created Live USB by applying the utility to other pen drives and they were mounted as writable flawlessly.

P.S. There are no switches on the drive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Description of a live USB drive cloned from an iso file

When you create a live USB drive with the 'buntu Startup Disk Creator, `usb-creator-gtk` or in your case `usb-creator-kde` in Kubuntu, you are **cloning** from the iso file to the target device, the USB drive. This means that the content is copied byte for byte, and the partitioning and file systems are inherited. The main partition has an ISO 9660 file system, which is read only by design; therefore all files and directories typically lack write permissions (to even prevent attempts to write). (It was originally made for CD-Rs.)

### Creating a partition behind the cloned image

- Several tools, including gparted, cannot modify such a USB boot drive, only repartition (re-format) it.
- However, in 'buntu 19.10 (and newer versions including Focal Fossa to be released in April as 20.04 LTS and Debian 10 live), using a suitable tool you *can* add a read/write partition behind the cloned image and use that to
- make a persistent live drive, where you can not only store data but also install program packages that survive reboot
- add a usbdata partition for storage and transfer to computers running Windows.

You can make a persistent live drive with the text mode tool [mkusb-minp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp). You can make either a persistent live drive or a drive with a usbdata partition with the more convenient and safer tool [**mkusb-plug**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug).

### Persistent live drive with usbdata partition

If you want a persistent live drive *and* a usbdata partition for storage and transfer to computers running Windows, you can use [**mkusb version 12 alias mkusb-dus**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). It works with all current versions of Ubuntu and the Ubuntu family flavours (including Kubuntu). It works also with Debian 10 live, the current version of Debian.

### General describing link

[How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: Thanks. mkusb-plug did the trick for me. mkusb-minp didn't create a bootable usb. But I may have used it in a wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @ka3ak :-)  I'm glad that you succeeded with mkusb-plug. mkusb-minp is more difficult to use. Maybe you were affected by one of the bug-fixes in mkusb-plug, that are not back-ported to the older mkusb-minp. I might replace/upgrade mkusb-minp to mkusb-sedd, which is the 'doer' part of mkusb-plug. -- My conclusion is that I should focus (even more) on mkusb-plug and leave mkusb-minp for those who want or need a command line tool.